# PySide - QSvgWidget renders embedded SVG files incorrectly

Tags: python, svg, pyside, qwidget

I try to render embedded svg file using QSvgWidget. My file "front.svg" looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" id="svgfile">
<rect style="fill:#ff0000;" id="rect1" width="150" height="200"/>

<svg x="100" y="100">
    <rect style="fill:#00ff00;" id="rect2" width="200" height="120"/>
</svg>
</svg>
```

This file looks quite normal in Chrome, or Inkscape, but in svgwidget it looks strange. Only green rectangle is visible, and red is very small, and hidden behind the green one.
Here is my python code:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication
from PySide.QtSvg import QSvgWidget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = QSvgWidget('front.svg')
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Does anybody knows, whether I do something wrong, or is it some bug in PySide?

Comment: This is not about programming embedded systems.  Retagged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some workaround to this issue. Now I'm using QGraphicsWebView instead of QSvgWidget. Here is my Python code (svg file remains unchanged):

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView
from PySide.QtWebKit import QGraphicsWebView

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    item = QGraphicsWebView()
    item.load('front.svg')
    view = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    scene.addItem(item)
    view.setScene(scene)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It's strange, that QT renders svg files correctly with this widget, and totally wrong using dedicated widget (I also had problems with "text" elements).
But now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it to render correctly by removing the extra internal `<svg>` tag, and moving the x and y attributes to the `<rect>` element:

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" id="svgfile">
<rect style="fill:#ff0000;" id="rect1" width="150" height="200"/>
<rect style="fill:#00ff00;" id="rect2" x="100" y="100" width="200" height="120"/>
</svg>
```

I assume this is a contrived example to test that specific case, though? Is there a reason you need nested `<svg>` elements?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason, why I need nested SVG elements. I want to load external file with logo, into my file with a t-shirt. It's difficult to "translate" all attributes of a svg element. I also tried to substitute svg element with g element, but again - it's rather difficult to properly translate all attributes like "viewBox", and moreover I don't know what would happen with namespaces if this logo file would have some additional namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

For me, *Inkscape* rendered your SVG file as you intended, but there is an issue with the group object that's created by the extra, embedded  object in PyQt4, where I observed the same as you. So I'm fairly certain that it's an issue with your SVG structure, rather than PySide.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For my future self:

```py
import sys

from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app: QtWidgets.QApplication = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    view: QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    with open('front.svg', 'rb') as f_in:
        view.setContent(f_in.read(), mimeType='image/svg+xml')
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```